# Submit value to json child object using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a form in an html page. I want to submit values to the following api using ajax.

```
{
    "userName": "john",
    "description": "funny dood",
    "address": 
        {
            "addressLine1": "house number from formdata",
            "addressLine2": "some value picked from form",
            "daDa": "some val from form"
        }
    
}
```

I am using the following snippet to submit to the api using jquery ajax:

```
function AjaxSubmit(form_Data){
var ajaxOptions =
    {
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "multipart/form-data",        
        url: "/api/Users/",
        data: form_Data,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            window.location.href = "/Home/Index"
        }
    }

    if ($(form_Data).attr('enctype') == "multipart/form-data") {
        ajaxOptions['contentType'] = false;
        ajaxOptions['processData'] = false;
    }

    $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    return false;
}
```

The issue is how can i pass the address values to various fields inside the address object.
The api is built on .net core, just fyi.
Thanks :)

Comment: If I get it right you need to retrieve data from different fields from the form and then put them in a JS object like this: `var un = $('#userNameInput').val(); ...;  apiData = {userName:un, description: desc, address: {addressLine1: al1, ... }};`  and then send the serialized object.

Comment: Sort of yes. Since its inside form, i am getting all fields as a whole. Then serialize and pass to the above mentioned method ajaxsubmit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your problem that how to use JS getting an object `form_Data` ?

Maybe this is your issue:

```js
var form_Data = {};
var userName = ${'#some_id1').val();
var description = ${'#some_id2').val();
var addressLine1 = ${'#some_id3').val();
var addressLine2 = ${'#some_id4').val();
var daDa = ${'#some_id5').val();
form_Data['userName'] = userName;
form_Data['description'] = description;
form_Data['address'] = {};
form_Data['address']['addressLine1'] = addressLine1;
form_Data['address']['addressLine2'] = addressLine2;
form_Data['address']['daDa'] = daDa;
```

Comment: Thanks bro :)
Used the same code, but used $('input[name=nameValue]').val(), for my case.

Answer (score 0):

**parametername** is varibales in the controller.

```js
function AjaxSubmit(form_Data){
var ajaxOptions =
    {
        url: "/api/Users/",
        type:"POST",        
        data: JSON.stringify({parametername: form_Data}), 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            window.location.href = "/Home/Index"
        }
    }

    if ($(form_Data).attr('enctype') == "multipart/form-data") {
        ajaxOptions['contentType'] = false;
        ajaxOptions['processData'] = false;
    }

    $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    return false;
}
```